# How to convert boost::gregorian::date to mm/dd/yyyy format and vice versa?

Tags: c++, boost, time

Boost has several functions converting to other string formats described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html), but there is no conversion into the necessary `mm/dd/yyyy` format. Currently I am doing it the following way:

```cpp
 std::string dateAsMMDDYYYY( const boost::gregorian::date& date )
 {
    std::string yyyymmdd = boost::gregorian::to_iso_string( date );
    std::string ret = yyyymmdd.substr(4,2) + "/" + yyyymmdd.substr(6,2) + "/" + yyyymmdd.substr(0,4);
    return ret;
 }
```

i.e. just cutting the numbers out of the value returned by `to_iso_string()`. This seems very rude, and I am looking for a more elegant way to perform this conversion. Also I need an advice about how to perform a backward conversion (i.e. from 'mm/dd/yyyy' string to boost::gregorian::date)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

boost has fairly versatile [date/time IO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html) facilities

```
const std::locale fmt(std::locale::classic(),
                      new boost::gregorian::date_facet("%m/%d/%Y"));
std::string dateAsMMDDYYYY( const boost::gregorian::date& date )
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os.imbue(fmt);
    os << date;
    return os.str();
}
```

Inverse conversion:

```
const std::locale fmt2(std::locale::classic(),
                       new boost::gregorian::date_input_facet("%m/%d/%Y"));
boost::gregorian::date MMDDYYYYasDate( const std::string& str)
{
    std::istringstream is(str);
    is.imbue(fmt2);
    boost::gregorian::date date;
    is >> date;
    return date;
}
```

Comment: new for boost::gregorian::date_input_facet won't generate any memory leak??  I know it is const but still.

Comment: I got the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409903/should-we-release-the-allocated-resource-for-stdlocale

Answer (score 3):

```
 boost::gregorian::date d(boost::gregorian::day_clock::local_day());
  char date[10];
  sprintf ( date, "%d/%d/%d", static_cast<short>(d.month()), static_cast<short>(d.day()), static_cast<short>(d.year()) );
```

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to use a std::stringstream and output the date's month, day and year numbers separately and adding slashes between yourself.