# Should we release the allocated resource for std::locale

Tags: c++, boost

```
const std::locale fmt2(std::locale::classic(),
                       new boost::gregorian::date_input_facet("%m/%d/%Y"));
```

In the second parameter, we use `new boost::gregorian::date_input_facet("%m/%d/%Y")`.

Question: Do I need to concern to release the allocated resource?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The implementation is required to deallocate the memory itself (unless you specify otherwise):

> 22.3.1.1.2 Class `locale::facet`
>
> For `refs == 0`, the implementation performs `delete static_cast<locale::facet*>(f)` (where `f` is a pointer to the facet) when the last locale object containing the facet is destroyed; for `refs == 1`, the implementation never destroys the facet.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the lifetime management of facets is configurable. C++11 22.3.1.1.2
 /2 says:

> The `refs` argument to the constructor is used for lifetime management.
>
> —  For `refs == 0`, the implementation performs `delete static_cast<locale::facet*>(f)` (where `f` is a pointer to the facet) when the last locale object containing the facet is destroyed; for `refs == 1`, the implementation never destroys the facet.

So when you construct the facet, you can either ask the `locale` oject consuming it to take (shared) ownership of it, or retain ownership yourself.

You'll have to check the Boost.Locale documentation to see how the Boost locale initializes its `std::locale::facet` base.

Answer (score 1):

No, the constructed `locale` assumes ownership of the `Facet` and will delete it when needed.

Answer (score 1):

According to C++ References (std::locale, destructor):

> If the object is the last locale object containing a facet object for which it manages its storage, this may also be deleted.