# How can I convert the value in days_ in a boost::gregorian::date

Tags: c++, boost

I can see in a the debugger of VS, that a variable which is a `boost::gregorian::date` contains a member `days_` being `2465846`.

Is there a way to transform this in to a dd/mm/yy on paper or Excel ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert boost::gregorian::date to mm/dd/yyyy format and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162457/how-to-convert-boostgregoriandate-to-mm-dd-yyyy-format-and-vice-versa)

Comment: I wanted to know what was the exact definition of this days_, i.e. # of days after which date, so I wouldn't have to run code for the conversion

Comment: Use the [source](https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/blob/develop/include/boost/date_time/gregorian_calendar.ipp#L112), Blue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "exact value of this days_" is, of course an implementation detail.

If you want a debug visualizers, they exist, e.g.

- https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/DebuggerVisualizers

  > Existing visualizers
  >
  > All visualizers are available in the svn at  https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost_docs/subprojects/DebuggerVisualizers. Currently, we support the following Boost types:
  >
  > - `boost::array`, `ptr_array`, `ptr_deque`, `ptr_list`, `ptr_map`, `ptr_multimap`, `ptr_set`, `ptr_multiset`, `ptr_vector`
  > - `boost::bimap`
  > - `boost::interprocess::offset_ptr`
  > - `boost::intrusive::list`
  > - `boost::optional`
  > - `boost::multi_index_container`
  > - `boost::multiprecision`
  > - `boost::shared_ptr`
  > - `boost::posix_time::ptime`, `boost::posix_time::time_duration` (two variants are available)
  > - `boost::regex`
  > - `boost::variant`
  >
  > There's also an unfinished visualizer for unordered containers attached to #4209. I'm not sure It isn't clear if it's possible to get it to work.

Since `ptime` aggregates a `gregorian::date` it will support this already.